# OpenVPN: Addressing remote LANs

Tags: routing, openvpn, linux-networking, dhcp, subnet

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now, but to no avail. We basically have an OpenVPN server to which our end devices need to connect. Some of those devices can directly connect to the VPN, others cannot, due to limitations of their software. Those end devices instead connect to a WiFi router (basically just a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian, hostapd and dhcpd running on it) which in turn is connected to the VPN.

Now, again due to software limitations we can't work around, all of the end devices need to end up in the same subnet and be able to see each other. That's basically where I'm stuck now - is there a way to make this possible? I've been thinking about setting up a central DHCP server on the VPN server which would basically hand out addresses to all devices, both connected directly and through the Raspberry Pies, but I can't seem to figure out how I would get this to work (and how devices would even find each other in this setup).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to to use the `tap` mode of OpenVPN on the server and clients. This will enable L2 VPN.

First you need to create a TAP interface on your VPN server:

```
ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
```

Then you need to configure the `tap0` interface on your server, and add a DHCP server listening to that interface.

Then, in OpenVPN, you use `dev tap0` as the interface for the VPN.